# iOS spotlight icon won't show

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

For my app icon I have crossed Iphone: **iOS 8 and later** and **iOS 7 and later** and ipad: **iOS 7 and later** then I transferred all 12 icons but when I do a spotlight search in my iphone the icon won't show up. Have I missed something?

Also, what does iOS icon is pre-renered option mean and do I need it?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Post a picture of your Asset Catalog.  Are you sure you added a Spotlight icon of the right size?

Comment: @JAL updated my post with a picture :)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the images are correctly sized: Spotlight images for the iPhone from iOS 5-8 have to be `58x58px`, as mentioned in the AppIcon image set's description.

The icon is pre-rendered option is used to tell iOS not to apply the default app icon mask and effects (like the gloss overlay on <= iOS 6) to the icon, and display it as provided.